# How to hide the bottom tab bar on the landing page in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have implemented a React Native application with a bottom tab bar using @react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs. The application also includes a stack navigator for different screens.

here's the code for the tabbar

```
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import LandingPage from '../screens/LandingPage';
import DisplayPage from '../screens/DisplayPage';
import StackBar from './StackBar';
import { styles } from '../styles';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

function TabBar() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator barStyle={styles.tabcontainer}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={StackBar}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: () => <Ionicons name="home-outline" size={20} />,
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={DisplayPage}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: () => <Ionicons name="person" size={20} />,
            tabBarBadge: 3,
          }}
        />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

export default TabBar
```

and this is for the Stack navigation

```
import React from 'react'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import DisplayPage from '../screens/DisplayPage';
import LandingPage from '../screens/LandingPage';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function StackBar() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={LandingPage} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Display" component={DisplayPage} options={{ headerShown: false, contentStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FFE5E5' } }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default StackBar
```

and my app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import TabBar from './components/TabBar';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <TabBar/>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I want to hide the bottom tab bar only on the landing page (LandingPage). I have already tried using options={{ headerShown: false }} for the Landing screen in StackBar, but the tab bar is still visible.

What changes should I make to achieve the desired behavior, where the tab bar is hidden only on the landing page?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to reorganise your stacks so that the Landing page is displayed outside of the tab stack.

```
//Add new MainStack that contains TabBar and Landing 
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function MainStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={LandingPage} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="TabBar" component={TabBar} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default MainStack
```

```
//Remove landing from here
function StackBar() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Display" component={DisplayPage} options={{ headerShown: false, contentStyle: { backgroundColor: '#FFE5E5' } }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

```
//Render MainStack
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MainStack/>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```